# Pausing FPS / CPU usage for static scenes in Unity3D for cross platform development

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'd like to use Unity for cross platform non game development but the battery consumption is painful. Most of the usage is read only / static, i.e., the canvas doesn't change, just panning at most (sometimes zooming, but not frequent). Is it possible to turn the FPS to 0 and reduce CPU usage?

Answer (score 2):

Hesitant "yes" because there might be side effects you'll have to handle on your own that aside from some general predictions I cannot know, or may not actually save any CPU usage.

But you can try fiddling with [`Time.timeScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html) so that the game updates less frequently, but it has some rather wide-ranging implications (if TimeScale is 0, then your panning and zooming aren't going to work *either* if they're reliant on either deltaTime (which would be zero) or use FixedUpdate (which won't be called)).

Generally speaking though, if something's using a lot of CPU then you need to go in and figure out why and optimize it. Use [the Profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html). If you're absolutely sure that your application is doing *nothing* and the CPU is still cranked, then there might not *be* anything you can do (it's an Engine problem).

Comment: `Time.timeScale` will *not* update your game less frequently, it will only slow down the progression of `Time.time`.

Comment: `FixedUpdate` definitely depends on the timeScale, as Unity's own documentation notes that if timeScale is 0, Fixed Update is not called. However, the point remains, if the CPU is spinning, profile it.

Comment: Of course FixedUpdate is dependant on time, as it is called at fixed time intervals. However the impact of this is insignificant next to the power consumption of a GPU rendering at 60 fps, unless you actually have many FixedUpdate methods and/or do **heavy** processing in them.

Comment: @ThomasHilbert Correct, but without knowing what the Asker is doing, whether or not this is true is indeterminate.

Answer (score 1):

`Application.targetFrameRate` sets how many frames per second will be calculated and rendered, so setting this to a low value will actually save power. Not sure how well supported this is on mobile devices though. Especially iOS frame rate may depend on a static setting inside your XCode project.

The Unity documentation for `Application.targetFrameRate` states:

```
- On mobile platforms the default frame rate is less than the maximum
  achievable frame rate due to need to conserve battery power. Typically
  on mobile platforms the default frame rate is 30 frames per second.
```

This should mean that setting the target frame rate to a lower value will consume less battery power.

Comment: Thanks, this looks good.  Will accept in a week or so if nothing else pops up better.

Comment: @Blaze Please when you accept (any) solution, could you add in the comment the result of you search? Thanks a lot!